# SQL query to achieve those rows which matches for two(or more) column value pair list

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-9.5

Suppose, there is a table users_customers which has three column user_id,customer_id and id. This table gives information about which user is assigned to which customer and vice-versa.

Now, I have a list of pair of user_id and customer_id. I know SQL query for to get row for a single pair of user_id and customer_id.

That is, 
`select * from users_customers where user_id in(uId) and customer_id in (cId)`.

But, how to get for all pairs in one go without executing query again and again for different pair. I am using postgresql 9.6. And, I will use alternate of this query in Spring Data JPA.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your actual problem is, but you can use `in` with tuples:

```
where (user_id, customer_id) in ( (u1, c1), (u2, c2), . . . )
```

You can also pass in multiple values as an array.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. This is what i wanted in native query but now i am struggling with alternate query of this in spring data jpa with dynamic values.